# AttributeError when running rqt commands

Tags: python, ros, rqt

I am trying to use rqt in ROS hydro but I see the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/ros/hydro/bin/rqt_graph", line 8, in 
>       sys.exit(main.main(sys.argv, standalone='rqt_graph.ros_graph.RosGraph'))   File
>   "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 59,
>   in main
>       return super(Main, self).main(argv, standalone=standalone, plugin_argument_provider=plugin_argument_provider,
>   plugin_manager_settings_prefix=str(hash(os.environ['ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'])))
>   File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/main.py", line
>   336, in main
>       from python_qt_binding import QT_BINDING   File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/**init**.py",
>   line 55, in 
>       from .binding_helper import loadUi, QT_BINDING, QT_BINDING_MODULES, QT_BINDING_VERSION  # @UnusedImport   File
>   "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py",
>   line 265, in 
>       getattr(sys, 'SELECT_QT_BINDING_ORDER', None),   File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py",
>   line 84, in _select_qt_binding
>       QT_BINDING_VERSION = binding_loader(required_modules, optional_modules)   File
>   "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py",
>   line 139, in _load_pyqt
>       _named_import('PyQt4.%s' % module_name)   File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py",
>   line 106, in _named_import
>       module = builtins.**import**(name) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '**import**'

Comment: please format your error message block by highlighting it and pressing `Ctl + k`

Comment: Also, it's very difficult to answer this question without seeing the code you're trying to run.

Comment: I see this error whenever I use the commands which is related to rqt packages. such as:   rqt, rqt_graph

Comment: Given that, a title like "AttributeError when running rqt commands" is more readable. The current title doesn't give any indication of the error here.

Comment: How did you install this, and how are you attempting to run it? Please may you add that info to the question?

Comment: RQT will be installed automatically when you install full package of ROS:   http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu